# Capture network traffic as images

Tags: bash, tcp

I am trying to create a solution that scans all network traffic and pulls out the jpg and gif images. These images could be saved to a directory and displayed by any of several "slideshow" applications or perhaps there is a simple way to show them in real time.

At my disposal is a Mac Laptop running Mountsin Lion, a terminal, and the built in wireless.

Any suggestions on an app that already does this that will run under those system requirements or perhaps a simple set if shell commands I could put together?

Answer (score 1):

After a little searching I stumbled on some software called [driftnet](http://ex-parrot.com/~chris/driftnet/%3E) which is a network image sniffer, and is actually in Fedora's yum repo (and probably available in other distros).

Here is a description from the official site:

> Driftnet is a program which listens to network traffic and picks out
>   images from TCP streams it observes. Driftnet is free software,
>   licensed under the terms of the GNU GPL.

I didn't see a *homebrew* package for Mac OSX so you might have to download the tar.gz and compile it yourself. It comes with very good man pages and hopefully suits your needs.